# Android Wear App Crashes when Register a Sensor Listener

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wear-os

I'm trying to create a step counter app for Android Wear. My problem is when I Register a Sensor Listener

```
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

}
```

The app crash but if I deleted the code above the app works but of curse the sensor listener don't work so how can I make it work and here is the code

```
public class WearMainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mStepDetectorSensor;
TextView stepNum;
int steps = 12;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wear_main);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            stepNum = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.stepNum));

            mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            mStepDetectorSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);




        }
    });






}

protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepDetectorSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

}


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) {

        stepNum.setText(String.valueOf(steps));
    }

}


public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}


protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this,mStepDetectorSensor);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare these two variables inside the onResume method:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mStepDetectorSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepDetectorSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

}
```

and unregister the sensor in onPause

Comment: Thank you very much you made my day